# How to read only selected lines in a csv via pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So the `skiprows` argument of `pd.read_csv()` allows to skip the specific rows. But how can I read just the selected rows for a pandas dataframe. Like I have a list of row indices which I need to read out from the file how can I achieved that? Passing `skiprows = ~line_nos` does not work as unary operator does not work for lists.

Currently using this method to read out the lines:

```
def picklines(thefile, whatlines):
  return [x for i, x in enumerate(thefile) if i in whatlines]
```

And then converting the result into dataframe. But wondering if there's a better way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a lambda function to achieve this.

```py
# rows_to_keep are the line_nos you would like to keep
pd.read_csv(path_to_csv, skiprows = lambda x: x not in rows_to_keep)
```